# Is the diagonalization of a matrix $D$ always given by $\boldsymbol{\lambda} I$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, diagonalization

For a matrix $D$, is it the case that the diagonalization of $D$ is **always** given by
$$
P^{-1} D P = \left( \begin{matrix} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 \end{matrix} \right)
$$
where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are the eigevalues of $D$?

In our lecture notes on solving systems of first order PDEs by using diagonalization to put the system into canonical form, it says that we are required to diagonalize the matrix $D$ by explicitly finding $P$ and $P^{-1}$ and then calculating $P^{-1}DP$.

Is there any reason for using this method to diagonalize a matrix, rather than just plugging in the eigenvalues (as above)?

Comment: Be careful: the expression $\lambda I$ in the title you gave this question doesn’t mean the same thing as $\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For a matrix $D$, is it the case that the diagonalization of $D$ is **always** given by
>   $$
> P^{-1} D P = \left( \begin{matrix} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 \end{matrix} \right)
> $$
>   where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are the eigevalues of $D$?

If $D$ is diagonalizable, then any diagonalization $P^{-1} D P$ of $D$ has the form $$\pmatrix{\lambda_1&&\\&\ddots&\\&&\lambda_n},$$
where $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $D$ in some order (and occur with the multiplicities of the eigenvalues).

This follows from the easy-to-check facts that

1. the eigenvalues of a matrix are preserved by conjugation, and
2. the eigenvalues of a diagonal matrix are precisely its diagonal entries (and the multiplicities of the eigenvalues are given by the multiplicities of the diagonal entries).

> In our lecture notes on solving systems of first order PDEs by using diagonalization to put the system into canonical form, it says that we are required to diagonalize the matrix $D$ by explicitly finding $P$ and $P^{-1}$ and then calculating $P^{-1}DP$.
>
> Is there any reason for using this method to diagonalize a matrix, rather than just plugging in the eigenvalues (as above)?

While it's true that to know the diagonalization of a matrix it's enough the know the eigenvalues, for applications one often wants to know the conjugation matrix $P$ explicitly.

For example, if one wants to solve a homogeneous, linear, constant-coefficient system
$${\bf x}'(t) = A {\bf x}(t),$$
of $n$ o.d.e.s. in $n$ independent variables, the standard first step is to diagonalize $A$ (if possible), writing $A = P \Lambda P^{-1}$ for some diagonal matrix $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_a)$. Then, in the new variable ${\bf y} := P {\bf x}$ we can write an diagonalized system
$${\bf y}' = \Lambda {\bf y},$$
which is easy to solve: $y_a = C_a \exp (\lambda_a t) .$ On the other hand, our aim was to solve the original o.d.e. in ${\bf x}$, and to recover the solutions ${\bf x} = P^{-1} {\bf y}$ thereto we need to know the conjugation matrix $P$ (or more precisely, its inverse).

Answer (score 0):

The transformation $P$ also tells you the change from original $(x,y)$ to "new" variables $(X,Y)$ that will decouple your DEs.  Basically it tells you which *linear* combinations $X$ of $Y$ of the old variables $x$ and $y$ to choose to obtain a simple DE in $X(x,y)$ and $Y(x,y)$.

The strategy is then to solve for $X$ and $Y$, and then revert back to the original variables $x$ and $y$ using the inverse transformation $P^{-1}$.

In other words, if you want to express the solution of your coupled system in terms of the original variables, you need $P$ and its inverse.  If you are only interested in the stability properties of your DEs, then knowledge of the eigenvalues is enough.

... and yes $P^{-1}DP$ should always be diagonal.  That's the key since then there is no cross-terms in the DEs for $X$ and $Y$, i.e. the DE for $X$ is a function of $X$ only, and the DE for $Y$ is a function of $Y$ only.

Comment: ... and conversely, if $A = P^{-1}DP$ is diagonal, then those diagonal elements are the eigenvalues of $D$ since $A$ and $D$ have the same characteristic polynomial.